# Find all values for x and y, where x and y are prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

So the question is as follows:

> Find all values for $x$ and $y,$ where $x$ and $y$ are prime, and $3 (x+1) (y+1) \equiv 0 \pmod {xy}.$

I tried this and figured out that (2,3) is one of the solution. But I am confused how to prove that's the unique solution!
Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Have you found any answers?

Comment: It didn't take me long to find one such pair $x,y$. I am puzzled by seeing $x|x+1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes i found one value i.e (2,3) and i wanted to prove that its the only one.

Comment: @311411 i didn't mean x|x+1. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $3(x+1)(y+1) = xyk$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, so either $3\mid k$ or $3 \mid xy$.

- If $3 \mid k$, then we have $k = 3n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $$(x+1)(y+1) = xyn.$$
  We know $x+1 \nmid x \implies x+1 \mid yn$. Then, we have $(x+1)m = yn$, so $y+1 = xm \implies x \mid y+1$. With the same logic, we get $y\mid x+1$. If $y$ is an odd prime, $x = 2$ from the first relation and $y = 3$ from the second. If $y=2$, then $x=3$, so we get two solutions, $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$.
- If $3 \mid xy$, then either $x=3$ or $y=3$, since both are prime. WLOG, let $x=3$. Then, $$4(y+1) = yk.$$ Since $y+1 \nmid y$, $y+1 \mid k$. In addition, we know $4 \mid yk$. If $4 \mid k$, then $4(y+1)\mid k \implies y = 1$ which leads to a contradiction. Thus, we must have $2\mid y$ and $2\mid k$. This leads to the solutions $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$.

Hence the only values are $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$.

Comment: can you please explain from $(x+1)m=yn$, how you got $y+1=xm$

Comment: (x+1)m = yn, so (x+1)(y+1) = x(x+1)m (after plugging in yn = (x+1)m into the original equation), so we have (y+1) =xm

Comment: Thanks a lot...